# Why am I getting 'missing comma'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am completely new to SQL, and for a project for my intro level class.

I am getting a "missing comma" error for all of my `INSERT` statements when my numbers are in single quotes, and a "missing expression" error when they are not in quotes. I can not figure out where I am going wrong. Below is just one of my tables and an `INSERT` statement for that table, but this issue extends to all of my `INSERT` statements.

```
CREATE TABLE Cast(
Cast_ID NUMBER(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Cast_Member_Name VARCHAR2(64),
Oscars NUMBER(2)
);
COMMIT;


INSERT INTO Cast VALUES (17,’Tom Cruise’,0)
```

Below is the error I receive when entering the above `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO Cast VALUES (17,.Tom Cruise.,0);
INSERT INTO Cast VALUES (17,.Tom Cruise.,0)

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Please remove `sql-server` tag as you are using oracle.

Comment: Will do, apologies.

Comment: er..do you see the difference between INSERT INTO Cast VALUES (17,’Tom Cruise’,0) and (17,.Tom Cruise.,0)?

Comment: .Tom Cruise. is not a varchar. '.Tom Cruise.' is

Comment: yes, I'm not actually using periods when inputting the INSERT statement, but that is the output I get along with the error code.

Comment: ’ is not the same thing as '

Comment: @Ivar: good edits. Additionally, if you see the formulation "I am stuck for <unit> <time>" you can remove that - I see it a great deal, and it probably isn't very useful (either to helpers or readers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you created your SQL in a word processing program. These programs tend to use odd characters instead of "proper" apostrophes and double quote characters. The characters surrounding your string literals are not apostrophes; you'll need to fix them, as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO Cast VALUES (17,'Tom Cruise',0)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: @majordan95 - just to illustrate Bob's point graphically, here are a few "straight" single-quote characters mixed with the "calligraphic" single-quotes from your post (you can still see them in your post!) The "calligraphic" quotes are added either by your word processor, or perhaps if you copied and pasted, for example, from a web site where they were used. The illustration is below this Comment, shown as a separate Comment.

Comment: `’'’ ''’’’'''` - see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You miss quotes in Tom cruise. Put it query will cruise.
`INSERT INTO Cast VALUES (17,'Tom Cruise',0)`